# Is there a standard interface in .NET containing a single EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Is there a .NET framework interface like this?

```
public interface IEvent
{
    event EventHandler Event;
}
```

I can of course write my own, but I'll reuse it if it already exists. Could perhaps have a Fire/Raise method on it too.

Comment: Just a question. Are you from java?

Comment: no, just ended up needing it to force WPF, MVVM, attached properties and data binding to do what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there is not.

Typically events in C# / CLR do not use an interface base pattern as shown in your question.  This is much more akin to the Java style of eventing.  The closest item would be a generic event delegate which can be re-used instead of creating new delegate types.  This does exist in `System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>`

Comment: +1, you're right, it does look very familiar to Java's observer style (though backwards)

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, but there will be in .Net 4.0, `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` interfaces part of the Reactive Framework, see info on [Paul Batum blog](http://www.paulbatum.com/search/label/Reactive%20Framework).

This is how the interfaces are in their current incarnation:

```
interface IObservable<out T> 
{      
    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver o); 
} 

interface IObserver<in T>  
{     
    void OnCompleted();     
    void OnNext(T v);      
    void OnError(Exception e); 
}
```

Comment: I was going to mention it.  Very interesting will probably be as common as IEnumerable<T> soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such standard interface in the BCL or any other .NET class libraries, at least as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real match to this in the .NET world. Can I suggest though, that you look into an implementation of the [EventPool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EventPool_Revisited.aspx)? This has the ability to fire events, and the events can be described as enums (or the like).